# Python: colorsys.hls_to_rgb returning odd values

Tags: python, colors

I am currently trying to get complimentary colors in RGB format.  Following the guidance from [here](http://serennu.com/colour/rgbtohsl.php), I performing the following steps:

1. Generate random HSL color
2. Create complimentary HSL by doing `1-H` of previous color, keeping `S` and `L` the same.
3. Convert both colors into RGB

My code is as follows:

```
bg_color_hls = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
fg_color_hls = (1-bg_color_hls[0], bg_color_hls[1], bg_color_hls[2])
print bg_color_hls
print fg_color_hls
print colorsys.hls_to_rgb(*bg_color_hls)
print colorsys.hls_to_rgb(*fg_color_hls)
```

However, this is printing the following:

```
(0.5536645842193463, 0.489454360526385, 0.47696160643815266)
(0.4463354157806537, 0.489454360526385, 0.47696160643815266)
(0.2560034224515616, 0.5725687282723873, 0.7229052986012084)
(0.2560034224515616, 0.7229052986012084, 0.5725687282723875)
```

Note how the R value is always the same, and it simply switches G and B.

This is not how complimentary colors work.  Where is my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "complimentary"? It might be simplest to convert your color into a colorspace where computing the inverse works the way you want/expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you generate a complimentary hue.

You need to add 0.5, then take it back into the range [0, 1).

```
fg_color_hls = ((bg_color_hls[0] + 0.5) % 1.0, bg_color_hls[1], bg_color_hls[2])
```

Comment: Ah, of course.  I'm still getting something odd...my R and G and simply switched while B has a completely different value.  Edit: nevermind.  There'e more going on here.  It looks like it works. Thanks!

Comment: @MrTi, just an aside - this is going to generate some really ugly color combinations.

Comment: Well, I have limits set on my L and S, but I simplified the problem statement to make it easier for the answerer.